# Read the content of Email attachment to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm getting my Job logs to my Outlook email, where the subject contains most of the necessary details like what job, which day, what server and the status. I used Date as a parameter to get the email into Excel.

I'm trying to take it further. If a job fails generate a log either in the body of the email or as an email attachment.

For the log in the mail body I brought those to the sheet and parsed with the search term "Error" and captured the line.

For the attachment I can only save it in a folder and get the name in Excel. Is there any way I could read the content of the attachment, search for "Error" and bring only that line to the Excel sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\users\maharaj\qalogs\"

Sub GetFromOutlook2()
Dim outlookAtch As Object
Dim NewFileName As String
NewFileName = AttachmentPath & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("QALOGS")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime "GREATER THAN or EQUAL TO" = Range("start_Date").Value Then
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        outlookAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & outlookAtch.Filename
        Range("email_attachment").Offset(i, 0).Value = outlookAtch
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So basically this is not an outlook question but simply "How do I read the content of a file"? And we are talking about plain text files?

Comment: Yes, the log file attachment in the email will be either in bin or txt file only and there will be only one attachment per email. So there is one other thinking from me in Outlook macro if we can able to extract the content of the attachment and move them to the body of the email, i can extract them from excel.Just thinking out loud.

Comment: It's 5 lines of code and a no-brainer to read a text file with VBA. Numerous examples here on SO and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: hi FunThomas, reading text file from VBA is after saving the attachment to drive or during the process of extracting the email to excel, if so can u give link which would help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend using the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class instead of iterating over all items in the folder:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
           If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime "GREATER THAN or EQUAL TO" = Range("start_Date").Value Then
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

> For the Attachment i can only able to save them in a folder and get give them name in the excel.

Yes, you are on the right avenue. The attached file should be saved on the disk first. Depending on the file extension you can automate an appropriate application for reading its content or just using IO operations for reading the content directly without involving Office applications.